# Cannot receive push notifications in Android with trigger.io and parse.com

Tags: android, push-notification, trigger.io, parse-platform

---

I have just started developing an app for Android and iPhone with `trigger.io` and `parse.com`. Now I'm stuck trying to add push notifications to the app. I send test pushes from the control panel at `parse.com` but nothing happens on the Android phone I'm testing with.

Here's what I've done:

- Added the partners/parse section in `config.json` with `applicationId` and `clientKey` from the settings at `parse.com`
- Added `"event": true` to the modules section in config.json
- My config.json looks like this:

  ```
  {
    "config_version": "2",
    "name": "My test app",
    "author": "(my email)",
    "version": "0.1",
    "platform_version": "v1.4",
    "description": "An empty app created by default",
    "modules": {
      "logging": {
       "level": "DEBUG"
      },
      "event": true,
      "geolocation": true,
      "contact": true,
      "file": true,
      "is": true,
      "media": true,
      "notification": true,
      "prefs": true,
      "request": {
        "permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
      },
      "tools": true,
      "reload": true
    },
    "partners": {
      "parse": {
        "applicationId": "(my real app id)",
        "clientKey": "(my real client key)"
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Added the following code to listen for incoming pushes:

  ```
  forge.logging.info('Adding push listener');

  forge.event.messagePushed.addListener(function (msg) {
    forge.logging.info('Got push: ');
    forge.logging.info(JSON.stringify(msg));
  }, function(err) {
    forge.logging.error('There was an error receiving push!');
    forge.logging.error(err);
  });
  ```
- To test the app I connect my Android phone by USB cable to my Mac and choose "Run android" in Trigger toolkit in the browser
- In the log I see the messages "Initializing Parse and subscribing to default channel" and "Adding push listener"
- I go to parse.com Push notifications and see that there is one connected device. I test to send several messages, some in "Message" mode, some in JSON mode.
- Parse thinks that the messages get sent but nothing is logged on my side
- I also tested connecting another Android phone. Parse then indicated that there were two reachable phones, but the new phone didn't get any messages either.

Looking at the documentation and examples I can't think of anything else to try. I cannot decide if this is a `trigger.io` problem or a `parse.com` problem.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with push notification . I have not used what your are doing . I have used Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) and also used MQTT "http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/" both of them worked fine with me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a problem just when you're using the default broadcast - rather than a named - channel?

We have a fix for a problem with the broadcast channel on Android ready to be deployed tomorrow or early next week - it will be in platform version v1.4.27.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will test with a named channel and get back with the results.

Comment: Yes, I can now confirm that when I started to use a named channel the notification does indeed reach the phone. Thank you for your assistance and I look forward to the update!

Comment: @James Brady i m still failed to send push notifcation to the user using parse.com but failed to recieve notification in device

Comment: @roshammar i m still failed to send push notifcation to the user using parse.com but failed to recieve notification in device  is this parse.com issue ?