# Android parse.com Can't receive push notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, parse-platform

I can't receive push notifications, using parse.com service. 

I used a quick guide trying to solve my problem. I was trying to use channel this specified name and "" as a channel name. Also i found [Cannot receive push notifications in Android with trigger.io and parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499947/cannot-receive-push-notifications-in-android-with-trigger-io-and-parse-com)

**I succeed to send object to parse.com, and to subscribe for notifications (at least I can see my app in DataBrowser on parse.com)**

```
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.main);

          PushService.subscribe(this, "push", TestParse.class);
          PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, TestParse.class);

     }
}


 public class ParseApplication extends Application {

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       Parse.initialize(this, my_id, my_client_key);
      }  

}

public class TestParse extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.parse);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name="ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".ParseStarterProjectActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TestParse"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Recently I've noticed LogCat errors:**

> 02-21 18:17:45.381: ERROR/Trace(8952): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>   
> 02-21 18:17:48.534: ERROR/com.parse.PushService(8888): unknown host

I really want to receive notifications. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your manifest even though you are sure you put all required stuff there ? you may have missed something

Comment: what have you analyzed so far ? your application is created / started ? your activity as well ?

Comment: My Application created, started. It shows Hello World, and also it registered at Parse.com. I can see it in DataBrowser Tab. There I can see that it listens to "push channel". So I'm trying to send notification through "Push Notifications" tab from parse.com. Nothing happens on device

Comment: HTC One S and 4.0.3 emulator

Comment: any log on one side or the other ?

Comment: Noticed some errors. But app is working. Added them to question. What do they mean?

Comment: Do you see more than 0 recipients in your push notification log? These kind of troubleshooting questions might be better handled by the Parse team over at https://parse.com/help

Comment: In push log on parse.com I have 3 subscribers. I've tried to create  this project with Eclipse and IntellijIDEA - no luck. Maybe someone can provide working test application?

Comment: '02-21 18:17:48.534: ERROR/com.parse.PushService(8888): unknown host' would tend to indicate you are unable to register to the push service for a reason.

Comment: But I can see all devices at DataBrowser tab on Parse.com. I thought that is sign of successful registration. What can you suggest? I'm going to write a message to feedback@parse.com.

Comment: @KonstantinKiriushyn  u resolved ? how u resolved everything done but facing same issue in android ?

Comment: hi can u pls tell me i m doing same from android device want to send push notification by specifying objectId of user already available in Installation Table and User table can u pls help me howcan i do that i m faield to recieve notifcation here is the code .....http://pastie.org/10224527      how can i check what is wrong as i m getting success push notification message but push notification not recieving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse employee here. In order to handle increased load on our push service, we increased the number of machines serving push.parse.com. Some ISPs started having issues when DNS resolution returned this many servers. Last Friday afternoon, we launched a custom DNS server which works around these issues with 3rd party DNS resolution. This should no longer be an issue.

Comment: help for the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123625/how-to-clear-push-notification-alert-on-status-bar-android

Comment: help for this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506543/parse-push-notifications-crashes-eventually-on-background-in-android

Comment: @Thomas Bouldin i m sending push using parse from androi device using JSON Object with alert as well and title as well but i m not recieving any notification in android device

Comment: I suspect push isn't configured correctly. I'd try turning on verbose logging and checking LogCat. Try Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE)

Comment: @ThomasBouldin  where should  i use this code ? i m using inide success call back or failure call back of   parsePush.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {

Comment: I was going to say to put this in your application startup code. If you're sending pushes from the client itself, that's probably your problem. By default, clients don't have the authority to send pushes (you can change this in your Push Notification settings by setting "client push enabled" to true, but I don't recommend it). Try sending pushes from the data browser. In production I'd recommend sending the push from Cloud Code; this prevents an attacker from sending unsolicited pushes.