# How to clear Push notification alert on status bar - android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi i've used **parse** push notification in my android app.

i'm not using noraml notification. i've register parse push notification. The notification alert comes from server

device received the push notification successfully.

for example i've received 10 notification from server, if i open one notification on my device, the app has opened and the one notification has deleted.

My question is,

**how to clear the other 9 push notification alert on status bar when open one notification..**?

Comment: GCM push notification?

Comment: not GCM but same like that.  "Parse" push notification

Comment: dude i haven't worked on it yet so i can't help.thanks for clearing my misunderstanding.

Comment: yes i have worked on it.do u have any question related?

Answer (score 4):

Does android.app.NotificationManager.cancelAll() not work?

If you need to do something very custom, you can use ParsePush to launch an Intent rather than creating a Notification. You can then use a BroadcastReceiver to create Notifications with non-standard behavior (i.e. selective stacking, dismiss all when one is interacted with, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your launch activity:

```
String ns = getActivity().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ns);
nMgr.cancelAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this in your Main Activity**

```
 NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) get SystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.cancelAll;
```