# Parse push notifications crashes eventually on background in android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using Parse to push notifications in android but it crashes eventually on background when i turn wifi off.

it gives me error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.

here is my code

```
public class ParseBroadcastReceiverCustom extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent == null)
        return;
    ConnectionDetector connection = new ConnectionDetector(context);

    if (connection.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        PushService.startServiceIfRequired(context);
    }
}
}
```

and on manifest file

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and on main activity onCreate method

```
    ConnectionDetector connection = new ConnectionDetector(this);
    if (connection.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, RegisterForget.class);
    }
```

any help please

Answer (score 2):

1. `PushService` is complete deprecated with the new APIs, which you enabled by declaring the `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` in your manifest. You can read about the changes to push in the [announcement blogpost](http://blog.parse.com/2014/09/30/android-push-gets-major-refresh/)
2. Your answer is in the error message itself. Call Parse.initialze. Your activity's onCreate should have
   `Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR APPLICATION ID", "YOUR CLIENT KEY");`
   If you put this code in an activity rather than your application, then Android might shut down your app due to inactivity and then relaunch it via the push intent rather than your launcher activity, in which case you won't have called Parse.intialize.

Comment: I changed call on my main activity to Parse.initialize(this,APPLICATION_ID,CLIENT_ID); ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("channel"); and removed my custom receiver and on Application class if  (connection.isNetworkAvailable()) {
Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(),CommonUtilities.APPLICATION_ID,CommonUtilities.CLIENT_ID);
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("channel");
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}  still not receiving any notification

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do with ParseBroadcastReceiverCustom. It doesn't extend ParsePushBroadcastReceiver, isn't registered in the manifest, and is overriding onReceive without calling super. Also, you should only need one call to Parse.initialize and it should be in your Application class, not an Activity class. Finally, please stop calling methods on PushService; you don't need them.

Comment: I am not using PushService anymore and not using custom receiver anymore as you can see in my last comment

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit unclear from your comment what your final code looks like. Editing your question to keep the code snippets up to date would help greatly. Let's start with diagnosing registration: 1. Do you see Installation objects getting created in the data browser? 2. If you call Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE) do you see any relevant information in logcat?

Comment: Ok let's start from beginning .yes i have client id and application id from dashboard and yesterday i could send many notifications to my application but when i turned off wifi it crashes eventually so,i tried to fix the bug but now i can't receive notifications anymore here is code in Application class Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(),CommonUtilities.APPLICATION_ID,CommonUtilities.CLIENT_ID);ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("channel");  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();  and on main activity ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("channel");and no info in logcat

Comment: FWIW, your saveInBackground() is a noop after the subscribeInBackground and you don't need it in both your main activity and your application. I presume an Installation for your device showed up in your data browser? What's the value of `pushType`?

Comment: also i send gcm id by this  ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        installation.put("UniqueId",registrationId); when i receive it in gcmintent service , when i send notification ,number of push sent to devices is zero but yesterday was one

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial step by step and it works now 
https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications